# Full URLs in emails in CakePHP unittest

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I would like to get full URLs inside emails that get triggered by my tests in CakePHP 3.2. I tried with the full-options for `$this->Html->image('image.jpg', ['fullBase' => true])` and `$this->Url->build('/', true)` but they don't seem to work in tests.

How can I force full URLs in emails while testing?

Comment: `Url->build([url array], true)`, is that what you tried?

Comment: Yes :) (edited question to show that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no host when running an app in the CLI environment as it's not a web request. You'll have to configure the base URL on your own.

Quote from the docs:

> **App.fullBaseUrl**
>
> The fully qualified domain name (including protocol)
>   to your application’s root. This is used when generating absolute
>   URLs. By default this value is generated using the `$_SERVER`
>   environment. However, you should define it manually to optimize
>   performance or if you are concerned about people manipulating the `Host`
>   header. In a CLI context (from shells) the `fullBaseUrl` cannot be read
>   from `$_SERVER`, as there is no webserver involved. You do need to
>   specify it yourself if you do need to generate URLs from a shell (e.g.
>   when sending emails).

So you can either configure it via `App.fullBaseUrl`

```
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http://localhost');
```

or a little more specific so that it only applies to the router, via `Router::fullBaseUrl()`

```
Router::fullBaseUrl('http://localhost');
```

You can either configure it in your application configuration (`config/app.php`), so that even on regular web requests your app isn't building it dynamically anmore, and consequently have it available in the test environment too, or, if you just want to apply to the test suite, put it either in your tests bootstrap (`tests/bootstrap.php`) to have it apply globally, or set it in your individual test case files.

That's what the CakePHP core test suite is doing it too btw. Whenever you're unsure, having a look at the core tests might give you a hint.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Configuration > General Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration)**
- **[API > \Cake\Routing\Router::fullBaseUrl()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#_fullBaseUrl)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.13/tests/bootstrap.php#L70**
- **[https://github.com/cakephp/.../blob/3.2.13/tests/TestCase/Routing/RouterTest.php#L74](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.13/tests/TestCase/Routing/RouterTest.php#L74)**
- **[https://github.com/cakephp/.../3.2.13/tests/TestCase/Routing/RouterTest.php#L520-L529](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.13/tests/TestCase/Routing/RouterTest.php#L520-L529)**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think there is a need for a link/reference to the App.fullBaseUrl entry in the docs from the helpers pages (the place where I looked).