# Router::url printing localhost in Shell in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.4

I'm working on CakePHP 3.4

I have a shell script to run as cron and send email to the user, email contains a link back to the website to specified controller.

To achieve this, I'm using `Router::url()` in the Shell to generate base url becuase `Html->link` is not working there

```
$fullBaseUrl = Router::url('/', true);
$scan_result_url = Router::url(['controller' => 'Notifications', 'action' => 'notificationRedirect', $notification->id], true);
```

But this is generating url with localhost as host like

```
http://localhost/notifications/notification-redirect/<id>
```

Same line in Controller when tested gives url to be

```
http://mywebsite.com/notifications/notification-redirect/<id>
```

**How can I get full url in Shell. My website is hosted on server and using `mywebsite.com` to access it?**

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785795/full-urls-in-emails-in-cakephp-unittest**

Answer (score 0):

Cron won't pick the server url in your application. You'll need to set a constant in the config file and use that only.
To do it the cake way, have a look at this [Full base url example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109785/creating-full-url-from-cakephp-2-1-2-console-shell)

Comment: The linked question is about CakePHP 2, that won't work in CakePHP 3.

Comment: Yes, I tried that link but it is for 2.0